# Swift casts Bool to NSNumber using 'as' operator

Tags: ios, swift, casting

I found an interesting code in my project and I'm wondering how it even works. If I simplify it, in a playground it looks like this:

```
var b: Bool = true
var n: NSNumber = b as NSNumber
```

I don't understand why `as` operator casts `Bool` to `NSNumber`. Documentation for `as` gives the only example for using it, namely for checking a type of an element in the array of `[Any]`. That's an example from Docs and that's how I expected `as` to be used:

```
var things = [Any]()
for thing in things {
    switch thing {
    case 0 as Int:
    case 0 as Double:
```

I didn't expect `as` to do a real casting. Where can I read more about it?
When I try similar code with `Int` instead of `NSNumber`, it doesn't compile:

```
var b: Bool = true
var n: Int = b as Int --> doesn't compile
```

So `NSNumber` seems to be a special case? I'm confused. Can anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `as` operator can be used for two types of casting. Type casting and bridge casting. Type casting can be used to convert subclasses to superclasses (called upcasting) or to downcast superclasses to subclasses (only works if first the subclass instance was upcasted). This is what you see in your example with the `Any` array.

Bridge casting is however a mechanisms provided for easier interoperability between `Foundation` and `Swift` classes. `NSNumber` has an `init` method that takes a `Bool` as its input argument. The `as` operator in your example calls this initializer, so

```
var b: Bool = true
var n: NSNumber = b as NSNumber
```

is just a shorthand notation for

```
var b:Bool = true
var n = NSNumber(value: b)
```

`Int` and `Bool` are both `Swift` types, so bridge casting doesn't work on them.

For more information, check the [documentation of NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumber).

Answer (score 3):

From [Working with Cocoa Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html) (emphasis added):

> *Numbers*
>
> Swift bridges between the `NSNumber` class and Swift numeric types, including `Int`, `Double`, and `Bool`.
>
> **You can create an `NSNumber` object by casting a Swift number value using the `as` operator.** Because `NSNumber` can contain a variety of different types, you must use the `as?` operator when casting to a Swift number type.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple documentation **NSNumber** can be **initialized** with following data type and hence can be **typecasted** into them as well:-

```
open class NSNumber : NSValue {

        public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)

        public init(value: Int8)

        public init(value: UInt8)

        public init(value: Int16)

        public init(value: UInt16)

        public init(value: Int32)

        public init(value: UInt32)


        public init(value: Int64)

        public init(value: UInt64)

        public init(value: Float)

        public init(value: Double)

        public init(value: Bool)

        @available(iOS 2.0, *)
        public init(value: Int)

        @available(iOS 2.0, *)
        public init(value: UInt)


        open var int8Value: Int8 { get }

        open var uint8Value: UInt8 { get }

        open var int16Value: Int16 { get }

        open var uint16Value: UInt16 { get }

        open var int32Value: Int32 { get }

        open var uint32Value: UInt32 { get }


        open var int64Value: Int64 { get }

        open var uint64Value: UInt64 { get }

        open var floatValue: Float { get }

        open var doubleValue: Double { get }

        open var boolValue: Bool { get }

        @available(iOS 2.0, *)
        open var intValue: Int { get }

        @available(iOS 2.0, *)
        open var uintValue: UInt { get }


        open var stringValue: String { get }


        open func compare(_ otherNumber: NSNumber) -> ComparisonResult


        open func isEqual(to number: NSNumber) -> Bool


        open func description(withLocale locale: Any?) -> String
    }
```

So All of the following Examples are true:-

```
        let intValue : Int = 2
        let floatValue : Float = 2.0
        let boolValue : Bool = true
        let doubleValue : Double = 2

        let x = intValue as NSNumber
        let y = floatValue as NSNumber
        let z = boolValue as NSNumber
        let a = doubleValue as NSNumber
```

Comment: Initializing and casting are different things. You can initialize a string from an integer: `String(123)`, but you can  not cast an integer to a string: `123 as String`